# Truncate `TimeStamp` column to hour precision in pandas `DataFrame`

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` called `df` which has an automatically generated index, with a column `dt`:

```
df['dt'].dtype, df['dt'][0]
# (dtype('<M8[ns]'), Timestamp('2014-10-01 10:02:45'))
```

What I'd like to do is create a new column truncated to hour precision. I'm currently using:

```
df['dt2'] = df['dt'].apply(lambda L: datetime(L.year, L.month, L.day, L.hour))
```

This works, so that's fine. However, I've an inkling there's some nice way using `pandas.tseries.offsets` or creating a `DatetimeIndex` or similar.

**So if possible, is there some `pandas` wizardry to do this?**

Comment: So you want the same values but without seconds correct

Comment: @EdChum Without minutes or seconds... I'm only interested to hour precision

Answer (score 125, accepted):

In pandas 0.18.0 and later, there are datetime [`floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html), [`ceil`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.ceil.html) and [`round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.round.html) methods to round timestamps to a given fixed precision/frequency. To round down to hour precision, you can use:

```
>>> df['dt2'] = df['dt'].dt.floor('h')
>>> df
                      dt                     dt2
0    2014-10-01 10:02:45     2014-10-01 10:00:00
1    2014-10-01 13:08:17     2014-10-01 13:00:00
2    2014-10-01 17:39:24     2014-10-01 17:00:00
```

---

Here's another alternative to truncate the timestamps. Unlike `floor`, it supports truncating to a precision such as year or month.

You can temporarily adjust the precision unit of the underlying NumPy `datetime64` datatype, changing it from `[ns]` to `[h]`:

```
df['dt'].values.astype('<M8[h]')
```

This truncates everything to hour precision. For example:

```
>>> df
                       dt
0     2014-10-01 10:02:45
1     2014-10-01 13:08:17
2     2014-10-01 17:39:24

>>> df['dt2'] = df['dt'].values.astype('<M8[h]')
>>> df
                      dt                     dt2
0    2014-10-01 10:02:45     2014-10-01 10:00:00
1    2014-10-01 13:08:17     2014-10-01 13:00:00
2    2014-10-01 17:39:24     2014-10-01 17:00:00

>>> df.dtypes
dt     datetime64[ns]
dt2    datetime64[ns]
```

The same method should work for any other unit: months `'M'`, minutes `'m'`, and so on:

- Keep up to year: `'<M8[Y]'`
- Keep up to month: `'<M8[M]'`
- Keep up to day: `'<M8[D]'`
- Keep up to minute: `'<M8[m]'`
- Keep up to second: `'<M8[s]'`

Comment: Great answer. Waaay faster than `datetime.replace`, which is the most common solution mentioned on SO.

Comment: My dt series had a millisecond term (+00:00) that I wanted to get rid of. First part of your answer seems to round (take terms to zero) but not truncate. Second part of your answer with astype did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: for minute frequency all the three: 'm',  'M' and '<M8[m]'  throw error. Instead  'min' seems to work.

Comment: Super helpful ty!  Midnight hours (00:00:00) did not show up for me in `df.head()` so I thought there was something wrong after applying `df['hour'].dt.floor('h')`.  But there was nothing wrong, checking `df['hour'].loc[0]` revealed the correct hourly truncation.

Comment: As a note, to do something like "truncate to every six hours" you can use `.dt.floor('6H')`  See [combining-aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#combining-aliases) in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

A method I've used in the past to accomplish this goal was the following (quite similar to what you're already doing, but thought I'd throw it out there anyway):

```
df['dt2'] = df['dt'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(minute=0, second=0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
df.dt.index.to_period("h") # for the period
df.dt.index.to_period("h").to_timestamp() # for the timestamp truncated
```

would be the least ambiguous (more pythonic?) way to achieve this.
Using `floor`/`round`/`ceil` for coarser round (months, years...) you would get an error message

```
ValueError: <YearEnd: month=12> is a non-fixed frequency
```

See discussion here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15303