# Assign time element of DateTimeIndex to new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

im working with the below `DataFrame` and want to access only the time (not date) of my `DateTimeIndex`:

```
                    idle wheel  Induce wheel axial  radial
tiempo          
5/30/2016 19:37:46  -1,099.12   -1,048.78   -477.13
5/30/2016 19:37:47  -1,099.12   -1,048.78   -476.98
5/30/2016 19:37:48  -1,099.12   -1,048.78   -477.21
5/30/2016 19:37:49  -1,099.12   -1,048.78   -477.13
5/30/2016 19:37:50  -1,099.12   -1,048.78   -477.21
5/30/2016 19:37:51  -1,099.12   -1,048.78   -477.35
5/30/2016 19:37:52  -1,099.12   -1,048.78   -477.13
5/30/2016 19:37:53  -1,099.12   -1,048.78   -476.98
5/30/2016 19:37:54  -1,099.12   -1,048.78   -476.98
5/30/2016 19:37:55  -1,099.12   -1,048.78   -476.98
5/30/2016 19:37:56  -1,099.12   -1,048.78   -476.98
5/30/2016 19:37:57  -1,099.12   -1,048.78   -476.98
```

I want to keep only the `19:..:..`, not the date part.
I've been searching but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: use the split() function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate \`TimeStamp\` column to hour precision in pandas \`DataFrame\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773342/truncate-timestamp-column-to-hour-precision-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.time` on your `index` `'tiempo'` :

```
df['time'] = df.index.time
```

or, if `'tiempo'` is a `column` use

```
df['time'] = df.tiempo.dt.time
```

to get:

```
                tiempo  idle wheel  Induce wheel axial    radial      time
0  2016-05-30 19:37:46    -1099.12    -1048.78           -477.13  19:37:46
1  2016-05-30 19:37:47    -1099.12    -1048.78           -476.98  19:37:47
2  2016-05-30 19:37:48    -1099.12    -1048.78           -477.21  19:37:48
3  2016-05-30 19:37:49    -1099.12    -1048.78           -477.13  19:37:49
4  2016-05-30 19:37:50    -1099.12    -1048.78           -477.21  19:37:50
5  2016-05-30 19:37:51    -1099.12    -1048.78           -477.35  19:37:51
6  2016-05-30 19:37:52    -1099.12    -1048.78           -477.13  19:37:52
7  2016-05-30 19:37:53    -1099.12    -1048.78           -476.98  19:37:53
8  2016-05-30 19:37:54    -1099.12    -1048.78           -476.98  19:37:54
9  2016-05-30 19:37:55    -1099.12    -1048.78           -476.98  19:37:55
10 2016-05-30 19:37:56    -1099.12    -1048.78           -476.98  19:37:56
11 2016-05-30 19:37:57    -1099.12    -1048.78           -476.98  19:37:57
```

Comment: Out of interest, how did you manage to copy OP's DataFrame to use it within Python, and how did you get the nicely formatted text to post in the answer back out? I'm often struggling with minimal working examples in df-related questions...

Comment: Look at `pd.read_clipboard()` and examples using `string.IO` and `pd.read_csv()`. Here I actually just copied to `excel` and I think there is actually an error in the `column` names now that I'm looking at it.. The rest is just using the SO formatting option (`{}`)

Comment: which command, and what's the error? Is your `Index` already in `DateTimeIndex` format?