# date - offsets.MonthBegin(1) returns prior month if the date is the first of the month

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a month column for a pandas dataframe. Changing "10/21/19" to "10/1/19". The following works for most dates, but changes the first of the month to the prior month:

```
ts = '2016-03-05 00:20:02'
pd.to_datetime(ts) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
# returns 'Timestamp('2016-03-01 00:20:02')'

ts = '2016-03-01 00:20:02'
pd.to_datetime(ts) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
# returns 'Timestamp('2016-02-01 00:20:02')'

ts = '2016-03-01 00:20:02'
pd.to_datetime(ts) + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
# returns 'Timestamp('2016-03-01 00:20:02')'
```

I've found a solution in the 3rd example. First updating to the end of the month then updating back to the beginning. I feel like there should be a more pythonic way of doing this given how common this kind of transformation is.

Comment: pd.to_datetime(ts) + pd.offsets.DateOffset(day=1)

Comment: Adding to @MichaelGardner's comment, add `hour=0,minute=0,second=0` to the list of parameters to set time at the beginning of the day.

Answer (score 1):

The required functionality is provided by the [`rollback`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.rollback.html) function:

```
ts1 = '2016-03-05 00:20:02'
ts2 = '2016-03-01 00:20:02'
ts3 = '2016-03-31 00:20:02'
pd.offsets.MonthBegin().rollback(ts1)
#Timestamp('2016-03-01 00:20:02')
pd.offsets.MonthBegin().rollback(ts2)
#Timestamp('2016-03-01 00:20:02')
pd.offsets.MonthBegin().rollback(ts3)
#Timestamp('2016-03-01 00:20:02')
```

---

If you have a datetime column and want to cut it back to months, you can also temporarily change the precision of the underlying numpy `datetime64` type:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2016-03-05 00:20:02', '2016-03-01 00:20:02', '2016-03-31 00:20:02']})
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df['Month'] = df.Date.astype('<M8[M]')
print(df)
#                 Date      Month
#0 2016-03-05 00:20:02 2016-03-01
#1 2016-03-01 00:20:02 2016-03-01
#2 2016-03-31 00:20:02 2016-03-01
```

(taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28783971/3944322) SO answer)