# Conver '%H:%M:%S.%f' to time in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have dataFrame with column called time with string values in format '%H:%M:%S.%f'.
Example of values:

```
0   00:00:01.233480 
1   00:00:03.212245 
2   00:00:05.172649 
3   00:00:07.109743 
4   00:00:08.934098
```

I have use this code to convert it to time : `df1.time = pd.to_timedelta(df1.time, unit='s')`

but when I run `df1.info()` I get

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 59918 entries, 0 to 59917
Data columns (total 1 columns):
time          59918 non-null datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
```

I am confused because time is in datetime64[ns], nanoSecond, but it should be in seconds.

This is important to me because I am trying to plot it later and this ns is confusing the plot.

Comment: If you want to round to seconds, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773342/truncate-timestamp-column-to-hour-precision-in-pandas-dataframe) is helpful