# Capturing the Timestamp values from resampled DataFrame

Tags: pandas, resample

Using the `.resample()` method yields a DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex and a frequency.

Does anyone have an idea on how to iterate through the values of that DatetimeIndex ?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.randint(0, 10, 100),
    index=pd.date_range('20220101', periods=100),
    columns=['a'],
)

df.resample('M').mean()
```

If you iterate, you get individual entries taking the `Timestamp(‘2022-11-XX…’, freq=‘M’)` form but I did not manage to get the date only.

```py
g.resample('M').mean().index[0]
Timestamp('2022-01-31 00:00:00', freq='M')
```

I am aiming at feeding all the dates in a list for instance.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It would be nice if you put an example of the data into your question so that everyone can help you better.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have just updated the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You an convert each entry in the index into a `Datetime` object using `.date` and to a list using `.tolist()` as below

```py
>>> df.resample('M').mean().index.date.tolist()
[datetime.date(2022, 1, 31), datetime.date(2022, 2, 28), datetime.date(2022, 3, 31), datetime.date(2022, 4, 30)]
```

You can also truncate the timestamp as follows ([reference solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773342/truncate-timestamp-column-to-hour-precision-in-pandas-dataframe))

```py
>>> df.resample('M').mean().index.values.astype('<M8[D]')
array(['2022-01-31', '2022-02-28', '2022-03-31', '2022-04-30'],
      dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Comment: This is really good, thank you but we have a numpy object in both cases. 
Any idea how we can stay in the Pandas world ?

Comment: The first case is a`list`. You can convert the numpy object to a list by using the `.tolist()` method. You will get the same result as the first solution.

Comment: Works fine if it is a date, but not if it is a period for instance.
Here is an example:

>>> g.resample('M', kind='period').sum().index

PeriodIndex(['2022-01', '2022-02', '2022-03', '2022-04'], dtype='period[M]')

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems to work fine both for dates and periods:

`I = [k.strftime('%Y-%m') for k in g.resample('M').groups]`